# Comparing specific column from a file to another file with specified number of times

Tags: shell, file, awk, scripting

I have 2 files say file1.txt & file2.txt.

file1.txt:

```
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000000819900000026572
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000003500000000026581
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000013450000000026591
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000011500000000026601
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000010000000000026611
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000010000000000026622
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000012855000000026632
```

file2.txt

```
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000008199,0000002657,F,3,img_F1_1.tiff
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000008199,0000002657,B,3,img_F1_1.tiff
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000035000,0000002658,F,8,img_F1_2.tiff
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000134500,0000002659,F,1,img_F1_3.tiff
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000115000,0000002660,F,2,img_F1_4.tiff
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000100000,0000002661,F,1,img_F1_5.tiff
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000100000,0000002662,F,8,img_F1_6.tiff
```

I have to compare entries of file1.txt(except last character) to first 5 columns of file2.txt. If it matches then I have to store entries of file2.txt to another file say matched.txt. If it doesn't then I have to store entries of file1.txt in another file say unmatched.txt. which works for me with below commands.

```
awk -F',' 'FILENAME=="file1.txt" {A[substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)]=substr($1, 1, length($1)-1)} FILENAME=="file2.txt"{if(A[$1$2$3$4$5]){print}}' file1.txt file2.txt > matched.txt
```

Now, I have one another problem:

If entries of file1.txt(except last character) matches to first 5 columns of file2.txt then it has to check last character of file1.txt(that will be either 1 or 2). if last digit/character is 2 then it has to search 2  same entries(first 5 columns) in file2.txt where 6th columns must have 'F' for first entries and 'B' for second entries.
eg:
file1.txt

```
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000000819900000026572
```

Here last digit is 2, then we must find 2 entries in file2.txt

file2.txt

```
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000008199,0000002657,F,3,img_F1_1.tiff
20170421,0000000001,00000009436781777,000000008199,0000002657,B,3,img_F1_1.tiff
```

which has both entries 'F' & 'B'.

If we find **LESS THAN 2** entries then we have to store missing entries into file say missing.txt. My command is working for 2 entries or 0 entries but for only one entry not working.

**Expected Output:**

missing.txt

```
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000010000000000026622 'B'
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000012855000000026632 'F'
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000012855000000026632 'B'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing only the *one another problem*:

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN { FS="," }                      
NR==FNR {                              # file1
    if(substr($0,length($0),1)==2) {   # process only records ending in 2
        a[$0 " B"]                     # create B and ...
        a[$0 " F"]                     # ... F entries to a hash
    }
    next
}
{                                      # file2
    delete a[$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 2 " " $6]  # delete the ones we meet (* below)
}
END {                                  # in the end
    for(i in a)                        # the leftovers (in no order particular)
        print i                        # shall be outputed
}
```

* The sample data is such that every record in `file2` will be removed from the a hash, not just the ones that have B **and** F records.

Run it:

```
$ awk -f program.awk file1 file2
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000010000000000026622 B
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000012855000000026632 B
2017042100000000010000000943678177700000012855000000026632 F
```